# Does Apache Log4J support Web Services Distributed Management Web Event Format?

Tags: log4j, standards

Does Apache Log4J support sending event via the Web Services Distributed Management (WSDM) Web Event Format?  I tried googling around and wasn't able to find it but perhaps someone smarter than I knows more.